# How to read internals of .NET Core console app from another app?

Tags: .net-core, ipc

I have a **.NET Core** console application which instantiates some public classes with some public properties. It runs a loop which under certain conditions modifies these public properties. These properties are updated several times a second for the lifetime of the application.

Now I want another application with a user interface to present the data from the console application. How would I from one application get data present in the public properties of another application?

#### Not needed

- I am only interested in public properties in public classes. I am not interested in private properties or fields or internal classes.
- The properties are very frequently updated, so I do not want to write to a file. Nor do I want to log to some cloud service such as Azure Application Insights.
- I would rather not do extensive or intrusive modifications to the console application (such as writing to a named pipe or a network socket) just for the other application to be able to read the data.

#### Thoughts

- Is there any attribute I can annotate the classes or their properties with?
- Do I have to refactor the console application into a class library that both the console application and the UI application reference? This would move out all the code into a class library and leave the console application with just a static main method that does one method call to run the code in the class library.
- Can my UI application attach to the process of the console application?

Comment: @KenWhite My question clearly states that it uses .NET Core. WCF is not available on .NET Core.

Comment: Does it need to be portable across different platforms? A message queue (RabbitMQ, for example) or a plain old TCP client/server (possibly using HTTP)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The two applications run on the same machine so a message queue is not needed. Also the properties get updated several times a second and the other application is supposed to update the UI in real-time, so a message queue is not desirable.

Comment: @Fred I'd suggest to investigate further about Message Queues. Some of them have a very low overhead above shared memory (which is not portable, unfortunately). They scale EXTREMELY well (and few hundred messages per second are a TINY number). They have a pretty low latency (few hundred microseconds but it depends on the exact hardware and configuration). Plus the usual benefits of a salable, well established implementation...

Comment: @Fred: Right you are. I missed that; my fault. I've retracted the duplicate vote.

Comment: What kind of UI are you thinking about? WinForms / ASP.net core? If WinForms, can you just put all of the code into that application?

Comment: @RQDQ Possibly UWP. Maybe Avalonia. I kind of want them in separate applications. So the UI application monitors the other application, and the CLI application is standalone. The CLI application is the real application. The UI application is just an optional thing to monitor it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this using [`System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext).

I load the assembly into my application at runtime and then instantiate its classes and read the public properties from my instance.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fileName = @"C:\temp\foo.dll";
        var assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(fileName);
        var type = assembly.GetType("MyApplication.Car");
        dynamic carInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        Console.WriteLine(carInstance.Color);
    }
}
```

Another way to solve this was by importing the project as a project reference. This way I benefit from strong typing.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between processes, you're limited to a few practical options (none of which you seem to want to do):

- Named pipes
- Some sort of socket based communication (not WCF in this case because you're using .NET Core)

  - This could be a custom protocol between your applications.
  - Could use an external message broker (e.g. RabbitMQ).
  - Could send UDP messages from the console app.
- File based communication (doesn't seem ideal for your scenario given how chatty the interface is).